# PostgresSQL - Want a tag_count from tags saved in arrays

Tags: sql, postgresql, tags, postgresql-10

I have a posts table in which tags are saved in arrays

```
CREATE TABLE public.posts
(
    post_id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    post_text text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    post_slug text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    author_id uuid,
    post_tags uuid[],
    likes_count integer DEFAULT 0
)
```

Have a tags table with tag_count

```
CREATE TABLE public.tags
(
    tag_id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    tag_name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    tag_slug text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    tag_count integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    tag_description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
```

Want to create a trigger function that will auto update tag_count whenever a post is added with tags or updated (like adding or deleting already added tags) or anyone can suggest a better solution. Tried the following:

```
CREATE
    OR REPLACE FUNCTION PUBLIC.trigger_update_tags_count ()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $FUNCTION$

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tags (
        tag_name
        , tag_count
        )
    VALUES (new.tag_name, 1)  ON CONFLICT(tag_name) DO

    UPDATE
    SET tag_count = CASE 
            WHEN ( tag_name.new AND NOT tag_name.old ) THEN tag_count + 1
            WHEN ( tag_name.old AND NOT tag_name.new ) THEN tag_count - 1
            ELSE tag_count
            END

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$FUNCTION$;
```

Comment: Can you share you best coding attempt at this trigger declaration?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.trigger_update_tags_count()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO tags (tag_name, tag_count) VALUES (new.tag_name, 1)
   ON CONFLICT (tag_name) DO UPDATE
   SET tag_count = CASE WHEN (tag_name.new AND NOT tag_name.old) THEN tag_count + 1 
                    WHEN (tag_name.old AND NOT tag_name.new) THEN tag_count - 1
                    ELSE tag_count
               END
   RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$;

Comment: Please re-post your function as update to question. Also make it as code. When additional information is requested always supply it as an update to the question not as a comment.

Comment: put the `new` and `old` before the columns names e.g. try `new.tag_name AND NOT old.tag_name` and so on